# how we can end the session of praticular user in XMPP and logout form the chat

Tags: android, xmpp

Button logout = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btlogout);
        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            connection.disconnect();
            setContentView(R.layout.login);


        }
    });
```

this code is allowing me logout but not killing the session and the page which i am redirecting that page's button is not working .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all send presence packet to server  and then you should logout. This way your session will be killed.

```
Presence pr=new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);
connection.sendPacket(pr);
connection.disconnect();
```

it will first made you offline and then after disconnect from server.Hope it will help.Thanks.

Comment: thnx its working but the activity which have redriected it that activity is not working its button's are not working

Comment: why did u called setContentView in on click of button?

Comment: for redirecting it to new activity

Comment: thats wrong.use startActivity() method and pass the intent to it.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186021/how-to-start-new-activity-on-button-click

Comment: Hello Nirav Tukadiya new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162006/designing-the-layout-for-5-inch-to-10inch-tablet-in-android