# Parse and Xmpp login at the same time with facebook intergation

Tags: android, xmpp

I am in the process of building a cross platform messaging application. Using parse.com and XMPPserver i have already created the prase user.
so it is possible to login into same server at the same time.
i am having pblm in login with the xmpp server.

Comment: Hello @Nirav Tukadiya plz ans this question is there any solution for this

Comment: hello is there any one to help me out

Comment: Hi, is it possible to connect my parse database with my own server, iv created an xmpp server with open fire, and theres an option to use a custom database as opposed to using the xmpp server default. since all my app data is already in my parse database it the wiser choice, now in order to hook up my parse database with my xmpp server, i need to find the parse database connection strings and some other information, anyone know where to find these ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse.com provides back-end support for your mobile application.You have already used openfire as back-end so you can not login to parse.com as a user which was created in your server.

There is a way that you can register user at both parse and openfire.
But it might cause some issues.It may not sync or you need to sync the data like user contacts,chat history etc. manually.For more do your own research.I don't know much about parse.
Hope it will help.